# помогите с ошибкой!

Tags: java

совсем начинающий, не подумайте.
вот такая проблема. это просто мини-игра "угадай число"

guessTheNumber.java:23: error: not a statement
else (guess == x); {
^
guessTheNumber.java:23: error: 'else' without 'if'
else (guess == x); {
^
2 errors

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class guessTheNumber {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 49);
        int guess;
        
        System.out.println("Write your number:");
        guess = keyboard.nextInt();
        
        while (guess != x) {
            
        if (guess <= x) {
            System.out.println("You're not right! It's higher!");
        }
        
        else if (guess >= x) {
            System.out.println("You're not right! It's lower!");
        }
        
        else (guess == x) {
            System.out.println("You're right! Keep it up!");
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *error: 'else' without 'if'* что в этой ошибке может быть непонятного?

Comment: *совсем начинающий*

Comment: Поставьте `if` после `else`.

Comment: спасибо, друг. я не знаю почему, видимо какая то еще другая ошибка была в коде до этого. сейчас поставил и  скомпилировалось. спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

У вас в блоке `else` имеется выражение `(guess == x)`, вы забыли `if`.

Сам компилятор вам говорит, что вы написали выражение без `if`. Будьте внимательнее и перед тем как задавать вопрос на форумах, попробуйте самостоятельно решить проблему.

А чтобы ошибки не было просто добавьте `if` и в следующие разы читайте ошибку компилятора, переводите её, в 90% случаев вы найдете решение.

```
else if (guess == x){...}
```

Почитайте в интернетах, про вложенные блоки if else, например тут:
http://proglang.su/java/operator-if-else

Comment: да, спасибо, просто проблема была в том, что у меня после (guess == x) и всех остальных стояла ;. сюда я уже закинул код без этой проблемы. поставил после else if и все скомпилировалось. Извиняюсь, что засорил ленту

Comment: Хорошо, что смогли решить проблему, а лента как лента. Ошибки компиляции лучше решать самому. Это сложно только на первых парах, привыкнете.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

Создаете файл с названием `guessTheNumber.java` туда вставляете этот код и все работает
`else` с параметрами не будет работать, `else` указывает на все остальное, что не подходит под `if` или `else if`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

  public class guessTheNumber
  {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 49);
        int guess;
        
        System.out.println("Write your number:");
        guess = keyboard.nextInt();
        
        while (guess != x) 
        { 
         if (guess <= x) {
             System.out.println("You're not right! It's higher!");
         }else if (guess >= x){
             System.out.println("You're not right! It's lower!");
          }else if (guess == x){
          System.out.println("You're right! Keep it up!");
         }
        }
    }
  }
```